# JMeter and Connect Times for SSL Connections

Tags: ssl, jmeter, keep-alive

For a benchmarking test, I have a very basic test setup wherein I have a single user looping for 100 times (loop delay 100ms) hitting an https endpoint (GET) with HttpClient4 implementation, keep-alive has been turned on.

In the test results, I have observed a pattern wherein every 5/6th request the connect metric is higher as if a full SSL handshake is occurring, check the image below. I am a bit confused with this, any ideas on whats going on here and why the connect times are higher every n request?

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

I was able to troubleshoot this issue a bit further today after turning on access logs on the load balancer (target of this test) and I can see a pattern wherein JMeter seems to be switching the ports on the client side every few requests - the frequency matches the pattern observed previously with the JMeter test results.

[image]

This should probably explain the elevated connect times, now the question is why JMeter switches the port?

Comment: That's entirely plausible. You would have to sniff the network or enable Java SSL tracing in the client to be sure.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer as to why JMeter switches the ports and thus having to create a new connection?

Comment: @neodymium No i didn't get an anwer on this one...

Answer (score 0):

This could be keep-alive, it certainly was for my issue. Firstly make sure it's enabled on the sampler. Then there's also this JMeter setting to say how long to keep connections alive for.

httpclient4.time_to_live

I've set to 120000 in jmeter.properties but looking at the docs user.properties file should be used. I know jmeter.properties with a setting of 120000 worked for me.

I set the value high to see if it is an http keep alive causing the port switch. Whatever you set it to you need to ensure the client you are emulating does the same.

As you get some quick results I would guess it is a short timer somewhere and not the server side not allowing keep alive at all. Wireshark can help you pin point this as it could be the server side resetting the connection after a certain time. The above config extends the client side time which may get the information you need, if not have a look at the server side equivalent which will vary depending on what services the endpoint.